# Tree traversal in c++

Tags: c++, tree, traversal

I have an assignment that is simple enough.  I have to create a tree using the this structure:

```
 struct gennode
{
 int item;
 gennode * firstChild;
 gennode * siblingList;
 gennode * prevSibling;
 gennode * parent;
};
```

My searching algorithm was this:

```
gennode* general::search(int element, gennode *t)
{
  if(t == NULL)
    {
      return t;
    }
  if(t->item == element)
    {
      return t;
    }
  if(t->firstChild != NULL)
    {
      return search(element, t->firstChild);
    }
    return search(element, t->siblingList);
}
```

I cannot figure out what is going wrong.  It does not seem to want to find all of the children.  For example, if I have 1 as the root with 2, 3, 4 as its children and 5,6,7 as the children of 2 and 8,9 as the children of 4, I cannot get the search to find 2's children.

I cannot figure out where my issue is.

EDIT:
Here is an example of how the gennode structures would look in a tree with 1 as the root and 2 and 3 as it's children.

```
gennode * one;
gennode * two;
gennode * three;

one->item = 1;
one->firstChild = two;
one->siblingList = NULL;
one->prevSibling = NULL;
one->parent = NULL;

two->item = 2;
two->firstChild = NULL;
two->siblingList = three;
two->prevSibling = NULL;
two->parent = one;

three->item = 3;
three->firstChild = NULL;
three->siblingList = NULL;
three->prevSibling = two;
three->parent = one;
```

Comment: What does siblingList refer to? As in, how is a single node a list? If you had a list of children wouldn't it be better to store them in a vector instead of a single node? Is siblingList the next sibling, and prevSibling the previous one? This is unclear to me.

Comment: with your example please given the gennode member values of the node with value 2

Comment: I edited the original post to include an example.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your problem is with the logic of searching **firstChild OR siblingList**.  That is, if you have a firstChild, you'll never look at siblings.  If your tree is built from back to front, it might explain why node 4 is searched, but not node 2.  Instead, you probably want  to ask whether search(element, t->firstChild) succeeds, and if not, fall through to search(element, t->siblingList):

```
if(t->firstChild != NULL)
{
  auto result = search(element, t->firstChild);
  if( result != nullptr )
    return result;
}
return search(element, t->siblingList);
```

Comment: I don't understand this code at all.  If a NULL pointer is found through the siblings, it would break.  I'm just confused.